# InputStream или BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, сервер

Я пишу игровой сервер, и тут возник вопрос, что будет более производительней? InputStream или BufferedInputStream(или вообще что то иное...) сервер в основном будет принимать и отправлять строки, иногда json конфиги. Помогите определиться)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InputStream` - это абстрактный класс, а `BufferedInputStream` - это конкретная реализация и вы можете создать его объект.  `BufferedInputStream` имеет  буфер в памяти, с помощью которого повышается производительность при чтении и записи потоков.

Неудобно каждый раз делать системный вызов, чтобы считать один байт несколько. Собственно для того, чтобы избежать этой проблемы и были созданы оболочки-буферы. Все что они делают — при первом вызове системного `read()` считывают несколько больше (в зависимости от указанного размера буфера, который по умолчанию равен 8 кб) и при следующем вызове `read()` считывают данные уже из буфера. Прирост производительности — на порядок.